# TWAIN blocks when user cancels

Tags: .net, scanning, twain

I'm using a slightly modified version of [Twain Dot Net](http://code.google.com/p/twaindotnet/) in my scanning application. The problem is, when the user cancels scanning using a button on the scanner (or if paper jams), TWAIN should show an error message and return with some failure code.

But instead, what happens is that the call to `DG_IMAGE` / `DAT_IMAGENATIVEXFER` / `MSG_GET` returns correctly with `TWRC_XFERDONE`, but the call to `DG_CONTROL` / `DAT_PENDINGXFERS` / `MSG_ENDXFER` right after that never returns. What am I doing wrong?

The application is written using WPF, TWAIN's messages are sent to a message-only window running on its own thread. The scanner is Panasonic KV-S4065C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it. I'm not exactly sure what's going on, but running all TWAIN methods on the same message loop TWAIN is set up to use did it. That also meant splitting the image transfer loop – after one iteration finishes, it enqueues itself on the message loop.

Comment: Can you elaborate what was your solution. I’m facing the same problem. In my msg loop where I’m calling DSM_Entry with DG_IMAGE / DAT_IMAGENATIVEXFER / MSG_GET the API is blocked and do not returns until scan completes.

Comment: @ikis Sorry, more than 8 years later, I can't give you any more information than what I wrote in the answer above.